# Set ws-reference from range-object - Runtime Error 9?

Tags: vba, worksheet-function, worksheet

I have a bit of code that did run perfectly, but when I copied the code into another wb where I wanted to do the same thing, I got *Runtime Error 9* at a bit of code where the VBA creates a reference to a prompted range-object - when it attemps to create the reference to the Worksheet in RngS (see below).

```
'Read new range object in input file

Set RngS = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
Set SourceWs = Worksheets(RngS.Parent.Name)
Set SourceWb = Workbooks(RngS.Parent.Parent.Name)
```

Then I went back to the old wb where I originally created the code and the macro stopped at the same line with the same error - what has happened?

*See complete code here: https://justpaste.it/5zbx4*

EDIT: I don't understand anything, now I get the same error earlier in the code when it attempts to create a Worksheet reference to the AppendWs. I only switched the order of ws and wb reference creating for the SourceWs/SourceWb - because I had it that time before and it stopped at Ws (it did Wb) but wanted to confirm it again..

EDIT: Shutting down the .xlsm it did run down to the SourceWs reference again, but staring macro again, it stopped at AppendWs-line.. wtf?

Comment: You have great complete code and understandable question. Can you try to take your "complete code" and make it really smaller, isolating the error? This is called [mcve].

Comment: OK - I got rid of everything not necessary to produce the error. See the link now. Still the code stops at - 'Set SourceWs [...]'

Comment: Sorry, can't access the link to see the complete code. In the code you've pasted though you could use `Set SourceWS = RngS.Parent` and `Set SourceWb = RngS.Parent.Parent`.  `RngS.Parent` is the worksheet object - you're saying "reference the worksheet with this name" - easier just to say "reference this worksheet".

Comment: Come to think of it - could there be a problem as `Worksheets` references the `activeworkbook` by default as you haven't specified the book, but `Rngs` could be in a different workbook?  **Edit:** Just tested and that would give a `subscript out of range` error.

Comment: Great ('RngS.Parent' instead of 'Workbooks(RngS.Parent.Name)' - that made the code run (through that issue anyway) - need to fix some things in the end to see it does everything! =) +1.

Regarding your 2nd reply - maybe it could have been that? In any case that issue/potential problem would be avoided with the suggested code from you?

Comment: Afterwards in the code where my issue is now is at: 'AppendRowCountry = AppendWb.Sheets(Rng.Parent.Name).Cells(i, 1)' it now says Runtime error 13 - Incompatible types. Should i code it now: ''AppendRowCountry = AppendWb.Append.Ws.cells(i,1)'?

... That did not work, I then get "Runtime error 438 - Object does not support the property or method".. :(

Comment: I think it should be `AppendRowCountry = Rng.Parent.Cells(i,1)`.

Comment: Try `AppendRowCountry = AppendWs.cells(i,1)`. 438 is correct because AppendWs alone specifies the sheet exactly, no need to qualify it with the workbook pointer.

Comment: @AcsErno  That'll be the one - I've only got the three lines of code in the question to work from. :)

Comment: I used `AppendRowCountry = AppendWs.cells(i,1)` - this solved it, but since that ref. was created with `Rng.Parent` - that should work too. Macro runs now as it should - thanks all! @DarrenBartrup-Cook & @AcsErno